# ¿Es una ofensa decir "Chale"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, méxico, vulgaridades

> A: Quiero ir a la casa de Juana a visitarla.
>   B: ¡Chale! Vamos para allá mañana.

¿Es una ofensa decir "Chale" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example that interjection doesn't fit quite well. Let me explain.

Concerning Mexico –the only country I've heard this word in, but the range of the usage is often spread by media– it isn't offensive at all. But the word itself doesn't sound very educated: never use it if you are trying to be formal. You could say it or hear it very often in the following situation.

You and your friends are leaving a pub. After paying the bill and giving, say 10% tip, comes the waiter and tells you he wants 15%. You say to your friends:

> - ¡Chale!, el pinche mesero quiere más propina. (The longer the *a* in *chale*, the more clearly you show your dissatisfaction or how surprised you are.)

*Chale* denotes certain unhappiness, or a will to complain in an unexpected situation, and it does so in a very informal way. Disappointment, in general. But it's far from being offensive.

Now to your example: in order for *chale* to fit there, *la casa de Juana* should possess an additional meaning, like "casa de Juana" being the name of, say, a *pub* or *A's ex-girlfriend's place*:

> Context 1.
> A: Quiero ir a la "casa de Juana".
> B: ¡Chale! ¿Ya te quieres emborrachar otra vez? (Vamos para allá mañana.)
>
> Context 2.
> A: Quiero ir a la casa de Juana, a visitarla.
> B: ¡Chale! Pero ya sabes cómo te trata. (Ni modo, vamos para allá mañana.)

Comment: respuesta buena

Comment: Estaría bueno que alguien aclare donde se usan estos regionalismos.
Nunca lo he oído en Argentina, España, Perú o Bolivia.

Comment: @Bruno9779 Hecho, añadí una línea. Mi idea es que esto tiene que ser especificado desde la pregunta.

Comment: @c.p. Yo creo que cuando se trata de un regionalismo hubiera que especificar siempre en que países se usa. Al menos para evitar confusión a alguien que está aprendiendo Español. En España muchos no toleran ni el "che" rioplatense, olvidate que "chale" sea bienvenido.

Comment: @Bruno9779 No veo por qué *che* pueda ser comparado con *chale*, ni veo por qué en España *chale* pudiera ser más demeritado que *che*. Más aún, no sé quien quisiera usarlo ahí. Sobre los regionalismos, estoy de acuerdo. El que contesta puede decir donde sí es valido, pero es imposible decir dónde no lo es. Creo que el rol principal, es del que pregunta. Quizá quieras contribuir con una respuesta a [esta pregunta del meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-to-deal-with-questions-like-where-is-this-expression-valid).

Comment: @Bruno9779 Como español, quiero decir que expresiones regionales como `che`, `dale`, `chale`... no se desprecian en España. Todo lo contrario, es lo que se espera como una indicación de la procedencia del hablante. Esta variación linguística también occure dentro de España. No solamanete con expresiones como `Ojú` pero también en la pronunciación `Ese señó arto qu'ehtá d'ehparda tié musha mardá`

Comment: Esta no es mi experiencia. Viviendo por 3 años en Madrid he visto casi a diario algún Madrileño negarse a entender un Rioplatense, corrigiendo su acento y sus regionalismos.
No todos los pueblos encuentran atractivos o positivos los regionalismos. En Italia por ejemplo pasa de una manera muy marcada. Los acentos y expresiones regionales son a diario motivo de burla.

Answer (score 1):

No es una ofensa en absoluto, es muy informal, y denota falta de educación por parte del hablante.

En México casi nadie utiliza esa palabra, y si la usas puede que lleguen a burlarse de ti.

Comment: Tal vez tú y tus amigos van a internados pero es una palabra de uso corriente entre muchas personas de diversas clases sociales y si bien, sí es cierto que mientras más bajo el estrato es más normal escucharla tampoco me salgas con eso de falta de educación o que se van a burlar de ti.

Answer (score 1):

"Chale" en inglés puede más o menos traducirse como "gosh!" o "aw man!", es una interjección que se exclama para expresar molestia por una situación. Por ejemplo:

> Chale, este camión ya no pasó.
> Gosh, the bus didn't arrive at all.
>
> Chale, otra vez me toca lavar todo.
> Aw man, once again I'm the one who washes everything.

Como lo han dicho antes, es una expresión total y completamente informal, aunque no ofensiva ni vulgar. En Guadalajara la escucho más o menos con frecuencia, pero esa palabra se asocia más bien con el DF, donde con frecuencia se expresa como "¡chale manoooo!" ("mano" es contracción de "hermano") con el tono característico del español de la capital.

Comment: ¿"¡chale mano!"? Tiene tanto tiempo que no escucho eso. Creo que el español defeño no es tan decente. "Chale mano" me suena moderado. Más común es "no maaaa", "no chingues", el más moderno "buey" (o "güey"). Pero veo tu argumento de comparación con "gosh" (+1).

Answer (score -1):

Chale hacía referencia a un chino, anteriormente se les denominaba de esa manera a los orientales y, por añadidura a las cosas que venían de esa región. Anteriormente las importaciones chinas eran consideradas de muy mala calidad, y era común que se dañaran o descompusieran rápidamente. Por ejemplo cuando fallaba un televisor se decía que "salió chale" (resultó que era un televisor chino), con el tiempo el término "chale" dejó se asociarse a lo oriental, no obstante se convirtió en una interjección que denota cierto fastidio ante algún tipo de infortunio, como cuando se daña un aparato (Chale con esta porquería de teléfono), cuando no alcanzas a tomar el autobús (Chale, ya se me fue el autobús) o cuando recibes alguna noticia no agradable ("Se enfermó de nuevo Juan" "Chale, ¿Y ahora de qué?"), o nada más para quejarte ("Chale, no deja de hacer calor").
He de anotar que la palabra ha perdido casi por completo su connotación peyorativa, no obstante es una palabra muuuy informal que se reserva a círculos sociales muy informales, ya que se considera que dicha expresión denota poca instrucción académica.
En el ejemplo que pones denotaría cierta inconformidad, es decir, B no tiene deseos de visitar a Juanita, pero lo hará no de buena voluntad.